# Layered Navigation Filter Problem. Working in Magento 2.3.2 but not in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I created this module about a year ago. Maybe because of `elasticseach` search engine or something now I am facing this error in Magento 2.4.1

> main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method
> Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::getCollectionClone()
> in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\ms241\app\code[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php:115

The full function in the `Attribute.php` file is like this

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (!$this->_moduleHelper->isLayeredNavigationEnabled()) {
            return parent::_getItemsData();
        }

        $attribute = $this->getAttributeModel();

        /** @var \[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

        if ($this->_isFilter) {
            $productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
                ->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());// ERROR HERE
        }

        $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData($attribute->getAttributeCode());

        if (count($optionsFacetedData) === 0
            && $this->getAttributeIsFilterable($attribute) !== static::ATTRIBUTE_OPTIONS_ONLY_WITH_RESULTS
        ) {
            return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
        }

        $productSize = $productCollection->getSize();

        $itemData   = [];
        $checkCount = false;

        $options = $attribute->getFrontend()
            ->getSelectOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (empty($option['value'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $value = $option['value'];

            $count = isset($optionsFacetedData[$value]['count'])
                ? (int)$optionsFacetedData[$value]['count']
                : 0;

            // Check filter type
            if ($this->getAttributeIsFilterable($attribute) == static::ATTRIBUTE_OPTIONS_ONLY_WITH_RESULTS
                && (!$this->_moduleHelper->getFilterModel()->isOptionReducesResults($this, $count, $productSize))
            ) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($count > 0) {
                $checkCount = true;
            }

            $itemData[] = [
                'label' => $this->tagFilter->filter($option['label']),
                'value' => $value,
                'count' => $count
            ];
        }

        if ($checkCount) {
            foreach ($itemData as $item) {
                $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData($item['label'], $item['value'], $item['count']);
            }
        }

        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
```

Module's `di.xml` file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="searchFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
                <item name="price" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollection" type="[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="searchRequestName" xsi:type="string">quick_search_container</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

If I do this change navigation filter won't show

```
if ($this->_isFilter) {
    //$productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
    //    ->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $productCollectionClone = clone $productCollection;
        $productCollectionClone->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
}

$optionsFacetedData = $productCollectionClone->getFacetedData($attribute->getAttributeCode()); // ERROR HERE
```

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: productCollectionClone in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\ms241\app\code[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php
> on line 121

And If I do this change navigation filter is showing but not working

```
if ($this->_isFilter) {
            //$productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
            //    ->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
                $productCollection = clone $productCollection;
                $productCollection->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
        }
```

> main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method
> Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::removeAttributeSearch()
> in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\ms241\app\code[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php:118

`[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php` has `getCollectionClone()` & `removeAttributeSearch()` functions like this

```
public function getCollectionClone()
    {
        if ($this->collectionClone === null) {
            $this->collectionClone = clone $this;
            $this->collectionClone->setSearchCriteriaBuilder($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->cloneObject());
        }

        $searchCriterialBuilder = $this->collectionClone->getSearchCriteriaBuilder()->cloneObject();

        /** @var \[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $collectionClone */
        $collectionClone = clone $this->collectionClone;
        $collectionClone->setSearchCriteriaBuilder($searchCriterialBuilder);

        return $collectionClone;
    }

public function removeAttributeSearch($attributeCode)
    {
        if (is_array($attributeCode)) {
            foreach ($attributeCode as $attCode) {
                $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->removeFilter($attCode);
            }
        } else {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->removeFilter($attributeCode);
        }

        $this->_isFiltersRendered = false;

        return $this->loadWithFilter();
    }
```

After adding this to di.xml

```
<virtualType name="elasticsearchLayerCategoryItemCollectionProvider" type="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elasticsearch7" xsi:type="object">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory</item><!-- Alioze AdrienF -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="elasticsearchLayerSearchItemCollectionProvider" type="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Layer\Search\ItemCollectionProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elasticsearch7" xsi:type="object">[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory</item><!-- Alioze AdrienF -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

And changing this `Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Sort.php`

```
private const DEFAULT_SKIPPED_FIELDS = [
        'entity_id',
    ];
```

To

```
private const DEFAULT_SKIPPED_FIELDS = [
        null,
         'entity_id',
    ];
```

I am able to filter products with single filter value like **one color** or **one size** but multiple selection not working giving me this errors

> {"0":"Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error
> log.","1":"
> #1 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at
> [app\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php:391]\n
> #2 [Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->_renderFilters()
> called at
> [vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php:578]\n
> #3 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false,
> false) called at
> [generated\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor.php:1076]\n
> #4 [Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->loadWithFilter()
> called at
> [app\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php:179]\n
> #5 [Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->removeAttributeSearch('color')
> called at
> [generated\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor.php:41]\n
> #6 [Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->removeAttributeSearch('color')
> called at
> [app\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php:116]\n
> #7 [Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute->_getItemsData()
> called at
> [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:202]\n
> #8 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems()
> called at
> [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:159]\n
> #9 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems() called at
> [vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter.php:148]\n#10

Basically, the module was for multiple selections of navigation filters. Like we can choose filter color red and black or any other color also. The same goes for other filters.

**I have checked this module is working in Magento 2.3.2 with PHP version 7.1.7 where Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search->Search engine is = MYSQL**

There are many files so let me know if anything else needs to be shared here. Any help would be great.

Comment: Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getCollectionClone()` just clone the object with php object clonning `clone`

Like this:

```
$productCollection = clone $productCollection;
$productCollection->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
```

In addition, it would be better if you change your cloned variable `$productCollection` to `$productCollectionClone` so that it would be different from main object, otherwise purpose of cloning would be lost and you would endup replacing your main object with clone object

Comment: It gives me  this error
`main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::removeAttributeSearch() in D:\xampp\htdocs\ms241\app\code\[Vendor]\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php:118`

Comment: I have added in the question. What happens when I try both of your suggestions.

Comment: why you are using function `removeAttributeSearch`? I am unable to find it in whole magento code base

Comment: I have added that information also in my question.